Swiper-Slider: How to slide through visible slides?
I have trouble with swiper slide to slide through the slides, if all slides are shown in current viewport.
The goal i need, is to get the swiper slide active class on the next slide.
the swiper configuration looks like this:
config: SwiperOptions = {
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  spaceBetween: 24,
  loop: false,
  freeMode: false,
  updateOnWindowResize: true,
  centeredSlides: false,
  navigation: false,
  width: 357,
  breakpoints: {
    1300: {
      slidesPerView: 3
    },
  }
};

my slide next function looks like this:
slideNext(){
  if (!this.swiper) return;
  let activeIndex = this.swiper.swiperRef.activeIndex;
  let slidesLength = this.swiper.swiperRef.slides.length;
  if (activeIndex < slidesLength - 1) {
    this.swiper.swiperRef.slideTo(activeIndex + 1);
  }
}

if i set loop to true, it works, but i dont want this behavior.
if the viewport is to small for all slides, it will work too.
any advice how to get this working if all slides are visible?
using: "swiper": "^8",

Your Q is not clear (Maybe add a screenshot).
